# SDL Mouse position Cropped after resize

Tags: opengl, sdl

I'm getting some strange behaviour with the mouse position in SDL. If I re-size the window bigger, the x,y positions from either mouse events, seem to be restricted to the original window Width and Height.

If there some function call that I'm missing to tell SDL that the mousing area has increased in size.

The relevant parts of the app:

```
void Resize(int width, int height)
{
    WindowWidth = width;
    WindowHeight = height;
    /* update OpenGL */
}

void Init()
{
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    Resize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
}

void MouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    unsigned int MouseButton = unsigned(Mouse.z);
    unsigned int b = (1 << (button-1));
    if (state)
        MouseButton = MouseButton | b;
    else
        MouseButton = MouseButton & (~b);
    Mouse.z = MouseButton;
    Mouse.x = x;
    Mouse.y = y;
}

void MouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    MouseRel.x = x - Mouse.x;
    MouseRel.y = y - Mouse.y;
    Mouse.x = x;
    Mouse.y = y;
}

int main(int agrc, char *argv[])
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        return 1;

    if (SDL_SetVideoMode(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE) == NULL)
        return 2;

    Init();

    while (!quit)
    {
        DrawScene();
        while ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            if ( event.type == SDL_VIDEORESIZE)
            {
                Resize(event.resize.w, event.resize.h);
            }
            else if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN || event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP )
            {
                MouseClick(event.button.button, event.button.state, event.button.x, WindowHeight - event.button.y);
                printf("event.button (%i, %i)\n", event.button.x, event.button.y);
                MouseHandler();
            }
            else if ( event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION )
            {
                MouseMove(event.motion.x, WindowHeight - event.motion.y);
                printf("event.motion (%i, %i)\n", event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
                MouseHandler();
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit |= true;
        }
        quit |= KeyboardHandler();
        SDL_Delay(10);
    }
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's your [SDL_VIDEORESIZE-triggered `SDL_SetVideoMode()`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_ResizeEvent) call?

Comment: Windows XP and SDL Version 1.2.13. 
Just seems a bit odd that everything works bar the mouse position, is SDL_SetVideoMode() really necessary, as it resets the OpenGL context. In my prototypes that's not a big issue, but further down the line it will mean reloading all OpenGL objects.

Comment: @genpfault Just tested it, calling SDL_SetVideoMode() does fix the mouse issue. If turn your comment in to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-calling [`SDL_SetVideoMode()`](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_ResizeEvent) in your `SDL_VIDEORESIZE` handler.

Comment: I've had a look at the source for SDL on http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL, and can see where it's being clipped. SDL_mouse.c lines 135-146, it crops down to the SDL_VideoSurface width and height. Which are only set by a call to SDL_SetVideoMode. It would have worked if the SDL_VideoSurface size was updated in the SDL_PrivateResize (SDL_resize.c).