# cannot retrieve correctly the mouse coordinates after resizing a window

Tags: c, sdl

Below is a simplified code showing the problem I'm facing.

The aim of the code is to create a 512x512 window, and change the Y dimension of its top level surface to 512x(512+25) when a left click is detected. When another left click is detected we put back the dimensions to 512x512.

When a left click event is detected, or when a `mouseMotionEvent` is detected, we display (with `printf()`) the mouse coordinate.

Strange behaviour observed:

When I run the code, I left click one time, the Y dimension of the window changes, but when I move the mouse inside the newly created area, the Y-coordinates displayed is stuck to 511.

Sometimes I do not get this strange behaviour, then the Y-coordinate can be bigger than 511. To get the strange behaviour left click several times, moving the mouse rapidly.

To compile (linux):

```
$ gcc -o test test.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```

Source: (test.c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

/* Prototypes */
void event_handler(void);

/* global variables declaration */
SDL_Surface *screen=NULL;


/***** MAIN FUNCTION *****/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    /* init SDL */
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erreur à l'initialisation de la SDL : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512, 512, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE )) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Graphic mode could not be correctly initialized : %s\n",     SDL_GetError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("my window", NULL);

    /* handle event & wait until quit_event is raised */
    event_handler();    

    /* quit & return */
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


/*** Event handler ***/
void event_handler(void)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    int quit=0;
    char message_is_displayed=0;
    SDL_Rect mess_coord = {0,512,512,512+25}; //{x_start,y_start,width,height}

    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = 1;
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    if(!message_is_displayed)
                    {
                        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512,512+25, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE); //change the screen size
                        SDL_FillRect(screen, &mess_coord, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255));  // fill in white the bottom area 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512, 512, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);
                    }
                    message_is_displayed = !message_is_displayed;
                    SDL_Flip(screen);
                }
                printf("mouse position: (%d,%d)\n",event.button.x, event.button.y);
                break;

            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                printf("mouse position: (%d,%d)\n",event.motion.x, event.motion.y);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working well without described problem when compiled using Visual Studio 2010 C++, on Windows

Comment: You mention that you click the mouse several times while moving the mouse rapidly.  I am wondering if you are losing mouse events due to a window size change and the mouse clicks are outside of the window area momentarily or that some mouse events are being removed from the message queue as others are put in.  The behavior you are describing sounds very situational due to a race condition between different layers of the SDL and your application.

Comment: See also this stackoverflow posting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272506/sdl-mouse-position-cropped-after-resize

Answer (score 0):

You can try following functions to get x and y coordinates in variables oldx and oldy as

```
int oldx,oldy;    
oldx=wherex();
oldy=wherey();
```

works in windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SDL1, I think you shoud add this to your code:

```
int x, y;
SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
```

Now the mouse position is at `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you press the mouse button, it resizes and then prints the button position. It is probably cropping that mouse position after the window is cropped.

Try resizing the window only on SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP. This way you print the current position when the mouse really clicked (SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) and then resize after it is released.